# Images with max-height inside flexbox have unwanted vertical space in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, flexbox

I have a group of flexboxes containing images, in a layout structured like this:

```css
.immagini {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.immagini img {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 0 10px 40px;
  max-height: 600px;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}
```

```html
<div class="immagini">
  <img src="1.jpg">
  <img src="2.jpg">
  <img src="3.jpg">
</div>
<div class="immagini">
  <img src="4.jpg">
  <img src="5.jpg">
  <img src="6.jpg">
</div>
```

What I want is the divs to have just a 40px bottom margin between them, margin which I gave to the images, and which works perfectly on Firefox. Here’s what happens on Firefox (and which I **want** to happen).

**What happens on Firefox:**

[image: What happens on Firefox]

But on Chrome and Safari the `max-height: 600px` unexpectedly spaces images between them vertically, as if they were centered inside an imaginary div with fixed height at 600px. I don’t understand why this happens. Here’s a screenshot of what happens on Chrome adn Firefox (and which I **don’t want** to happen). It obviously gets worse on smaller screens.

**What happens on Chrome and Safari:**

[image: What happens on Chrome and Safari]

Can you suggest a solution? How can I make Chrome and Safari behave like Firefox?

EDIT: Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/Ada_Snufkin/pen/rJjEda

Comment: add your code with link. I have checked with your code its working fine in my side.

Comment: Please share a pen link

Comment: I'm sorry, you're both right: here's the code: https://codepen.io/Ada_Snufkin/pen/rJjEda 
I also edited the post.

Comment: I can't reproduce the same output on Chrome as what your posted image shows. Is there some code part missing between the one you've posted here and the one used when made that screen dump.

Comment: @LGSon, the only missing part is a container div. But it's not relevant, because in the pen I shared I see the same visualization issues on Chrome and Safari and there's no container div, there: https://codepen.io/Ada_Snufkin/pen/rJjEda